# Extending the Parent pull down menu on Group Settings page under WordPress

Tags: wordpress, groups, menu, settings

I have 50 groups including main and subgroups. The Parent pull-down menu on the Group Settings page under WordPress only displays 48 items so I can't select the 50th group (Volunteers) as a parent of subgroup (Volunteer Emeritus). Can I make the menu longer or do I have to rename the main group so it comes earlier in the alphabetic list?

Comment: Do you get this on the AJAX pop-up ? That means, are you opening the Group Setting Page in AJAX mode ? If yes, you can try if same thing happens when you open the `Settings` link in a new tab using browser functionality ?